# how to format Javascript loop html table

Tags: javascript, ajax

my table columns are `amount, price, value, date, notes`

`addCommas` and `round` are formatting functions

the json data looks like this

```
[{"amount":"19905405",
  "price":"3.7",
  "value":"736500",
  "date":"2012-02-29", 
  "notes":""
},
{"amount":"10000000",
 "price":"2",
 "value":"200000",
 "date":"2011-12-05",
 "notes":"test one only"
 }]
```

inside the `$.ajax({... success:function(store){...` this is my javascript loop to draw the table

```
$("#table_a").empty();

var table = '<tbody><tr><td style="ba.....rest of header row string';
$.each(store, function(row, i) {
   table += '<tr>';
   table += '<td><span>' + addCommas(round(i/1000000,2)) + "m" + '</span></td>';
   table += '<td><span>' + i + '</span></td>';
   table += '<td><span>' + "$" + addCommas(round(i/1000000,2)) + "m" + '</span></td>';
   table += '<td><span>' + i + '</span></td>';
   table += '<td><span>' + i + '</span></td>';
   table += '</tr>';
});
table += '</tr></tbody>';
$("#table_a").append(table);
```

the end result currently looks like this

[image]

how do I get the loop right to add formatting to the cell data ?

Comment: What is the error/issue with your code?

Comment: When you say add formatting to the cell data are you talking about css? Please be more specific.

Comment: by formatting I only mean applying the `addCommas` or `round` function so 1000000 becomes $1m. the code above results in `NaNm` in table cells where formatting funcs apply, and `[object Object]` where `i` is not formatted.

Comment: there's no issue with `addCommas` or `round`, they work fine

Comment: What is `store`? `row`? your code seems to assume that `i` is an object, but i is the index of the item within the array being iterated

Comment: thanks Juan. `store` is the json data. what would you suggest changing ?

Comment: did that guy tick it down, then remove his answer cause he didn't like my response? it just a q&a site buddy, maybe you could relax a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it...

```
$("#table_a").empty();

var table = '<tbody><tr><td style="ba.....rest of header row string';
$.each(store, function(i, data) {
   table += '<tr>';
   table += '<td><span>' + addCommas(round(store[i].amount/1000000,2)) + "m" + '</span></td>';
   table += '<td><span>' + store[i].price + '</span></td>';
   table += '<td><span>' + "$" + addCommas(round(store[i].value/1000000,2)) + "m" + '</span></td>';
   table += '<td><span>' + store[i].date + '</span></td>';          
   table += '<td><span>' + store[i].notes + '</span></td>';
   table += '</tr>';
});
table += '</tr></tbody>';
$("#table_a").append(table);
```

thanks Phil Jackson

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2529958/1185018